# Disadvantages of using just Vector Stores

Tags: language-model, gpt, vector-database

I've just started with langchain, and one thing baffles me.

For starters, I'm using an in-memory vector store created from a local `csv` file

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import CSVLoader
loader = CSVLoader(file_path=file)

from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(vectorstore_cls=DocArrayInMemorySearch).from_loaders([loader])

...
response = index.query(query)
```

I've seen that under the hood is using `embeddings` API from OpenAPI, and for my specific use case (meaning specific domain knowledge) I find it more powerful than OpenAI's API `completions` endpoint (tried multiple models).

I feel that using a Vector Store or DB with `embeddings` API is way better than using `completions` API.

I feel that the similarity search does all the magic, and I cannot see the value of an LLM (at least at this point). What are the disadvantages or bottlenecks of using just a Vector DB and an embedding model?

Comment: Sorry, but what is exactly the question? If it works it works, end of story.